# Commutative operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the operation $⊥$ defined by placing, for every $x,y∈R_+$
$x⊥y=x^{\ln y}$. Check Commutativity.
My proof:
$x⊥y=x^{\ln y}\\y⊥x=y^{\ln x}$
How to show that $x^{\ln y}=y^{\ln x}$ or $x^{\ln y}\not=y^{\ln x}$?

Comment: Take the logarithm.

Comment: Use `$\in$` for $\in$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Qiaochu Yan commented, take the logarithm. Using $\ln(a^b)=b\ln a$:

$\ln (x^{\ln y})=\ln y\ln x$

$\ln (y^{\ln x})=\ln x\ln y$

By commutativity, both expressions are equal. Now, since the logarithm is injective, that shows $x^{\ln y}=y^{\ln x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the claim of commutativity is that  $x^{\ln y}=y^{\ln x}$ *for all* $x$ and $y$. So, either show that is the case .... or show that there are *some* $x$ and $y$ for which $x^{\ln y}\not=y^{\ln x}$ .. for that, just pick some concrete values of $x$ and $y$.